# Why is the texture image upside down in this example Dart ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js, dart

In the example program [given here in Dart](https://github.com/threeDart/three.dart/blob/master/example/web_gl_geometry_cube/web_gl_geometry_cube.dart), why is the image texture initially upside down? It seems to be flipped upside down, not rotated. Why is that?

[Here is the example running](http://threedart.github.io/three.dart/example/web_gl_geometry_cube/web_gl_geometry_cube.html), I am talking about the cube texture on the first frame when you view it, before it rotates. I made an example based upon this but I am upset to find the texture flipped upside down.

Answer (score 1):

> In the example program [given here in Dart](https://github.com/threeDart/three.dart/blob/master/example/web_gl_geometry_cube/web_gl_geometry_cube.dart), why is the image texture initially upside down?

For me, the example shows the texture upside down not only in the first frame but in all frames (by comparing the [texture](https://github.com/threeDart/three.dart/blob/master/example/web_gl_geometry_cube/textures/crate.gif) and the running example).  I am not sure why you and I are seeing different things.

In any case, this seems to be an old bug in `CubeGeometry` in three.js, which was fixed in [July 2012](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/825715b35594dde45bade8f6e7f9577d9ae2a550) but has not been fixed in three.dart.

Comment: Yes your correct, all frames. I just wanted to make it clear by only considering the first frame.